# jQuery $.post() a form with .serialize() / Where are my params in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, post

I've got a html form and trying to send it with jQuery to a php script. In this script i am looking for the params.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  $("#myselect").change(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("mypath/toscript/",$("#form").serialize(), function(data){
      alert(data);
    });
  });
 
});
```

I need all uri parts. So im fetching it with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

I am requesting something like this:
`mypath/toscript/?p1=A&p2=B&p3=C`

When i type this URI in the browser it works like it should.

But with the jQuery above i am getting with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` only mypath/toscript/ without params.

Using $_POST shows me the prams `p1=A&p2=B&p3=C`

So why? Where is the difference when doing a post with `$.post()` to typing it directly

Comment: `GET` for the start..

Comment: Is this request fetching data, or is it submitting data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST doesn't use the request URL to send the query string like GET does. POST instead sends the query string in the HTTP message body. When you type the query string into the browser, you are using method GET.

[Here is an article from W3Schools about it.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

That doesn't mean you should switch to using `$.get` necessarily though. There are drawbacks to using GET over POST, such as having a length limit or being less secure. Read the article to learn more.

To fix your code, you will have to choose which HTTP method suites your needs, and then align the jQuery and PHP code so that they both use the same method.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer! :-) I already suspected something like that. 
It is always important to understand what you are doing. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In your case try this will solve your problem ..

```
$.get("mypath/toscript/",$("#form").serialize(), function(data){
```

> GET - Requests data from a specified resource..
>
> POST - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource..

**from** [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

You should use GET where you're doing a request which has no side effects, e.g. just fetching some info. This request can:

> Be repeated without any problem - if the browser detects an error it
>   can silently retry Have its result cached by the browser Be cached by
>   a proxy

Comment: Sure, this will fix his problem, but its an ignorant fix. GET isn't something you switch to just because it's convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide serialize in formatted array way something like this

```
var data = $('#form').serializeArray();

$.post("mypath/toscript/",data , function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: According to the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/), `form.serialize()` is how its done. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Check out this [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post) it will better guide you

Answer (score 0):

Use parse_str to parse your serialized POST data into an array.

```
// $_POST['form'] : "num=12&obj=3&obs=text"
$form = array();
parse_str($_POST['form'], $form);

// you get :
$int_num = (int) $form['num'];  // 12
$int_obj = (int) $form['obj'];  // 3
$str_obs = $form['obs'];        // "text"
```

A serialized form data is commonly used to update a database, so it's recommended to use POST vars.